# why the ArrayList is Returning empty strings [] [] []?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, web

this is my DB enquiry function

```
        public static List<UserPass> selectAllUser() {
            ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
            Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            List<UserPass> usersPass = new ArrayList<UserPass>();

            String query = "select * from UserPass";
            try{
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
            UserPass users = new UserPass();
            users.setUserName(rs.getString("user_name"));
            usersPass.add(users);

            }

            return usersPass;
```

and this is my UserPass object get function

```
   public ArrayList<UserPass> getusernames(){

   return usernames;
   }
```

my servlet dopost is simply this

```
    request.setAttribute("users", UserPassDb.selectAllUser());

    String forward = "/testpage.jsp";
    RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(forward);
    view.forward(request, response);
```

and my display jsp page is

```
            <form action="TestServlet" method="post">
                <input type="submit">

            </form>

            <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">

                <c:out value="${user.usernames}"/> 

            </c:forEach>
```

UserPass Class

```
            /*
            * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
            * and open the template in the editor.
            */
            package business;

            import java.io.Serializable;
            import java.util.ArrayList;

            /**
            *
            * @author One
            */
            public class UserPass implements Serializable {


                public String username;
                public String password;

                public ArrayList<UserPass> usernames;


                public UserPass(){
                    this.username ="";
                    this.password ="";  
                    this.usernames = new ArrayList<UserPass>();
                }

                public void setUserName(String username) {
                    this.username = username;

                }
                public String getUserName(){

                    return username;
                }

                public ArrayList<UserPass> getusernames(){

                return usernames;
            }
                public void setusernames(ArrayList<UserPass> a){

                    this.usernames = a;
                }
            }
```

tried changing this  it tells me property doesn't exist when it does as far as i understand. am sure am wrong

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `getusernames()` which returns `ArrayList` and You did not mentioned `setusernames(ArrayList<UserPass> )`.

But, If You want to display Usernames, In JSP, Change

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">

        <c:out value="${user.username}"/> 

</c:forEach>
```

> How this works:

Here `users`is the request attribute which is a `List<UserPass>`. Now,When you iterate it using `forEach`,You get `UserPass` in `user` for each row.

Then `user.username` calls `getUserName` from `UserPass` bean.

In your case `user.usernames`, It returns empty `Arraylist`.

Comment: but when I change to username, it tells me the property doesn't exist at class UserPass..

Comment: can you share `UserPass` class ?